# Java Web Service Constructor invocation

Tags: java, web-services

How do you invoke a Java Web  service constructor. Ideally when does constructor invocation happen while you consume the service from a client

Comment: Please include which WS framework you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You do not explicitly invoke a constructor from the client. From a Web services perspective, you are invoking an operation. You have no knowledge in the client of how that operation is implemented.

The life-cycle of your server-side object is in the hands of your specific implementation of JAX-WS. Possibly, at the time your server starts, it will instantiate one or more copies of your service object, and so that's when your constructor is called.

In Web services, each operation is usually a "stateless" action. If you have some standard processing you need to do, you would just include that processing in your implementation.

```
operationAaa(final String exampleParam) {
    auditLog(exampleParam);

    doAaaWork(exampleParam);
}

operationBbb(final String exampleParam) {
    auditLog(exampleParam);

    doBbbWork(exampleParam);
}
```

Now, possibly, you may have the kind of processing that could be implemented in a Handler. See [this article](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. 
So if i have a set of statements to be executed each time a web method is executed rather than executing once when the server starts, where should it be put. I assumed, putting this code in the constructor and creating a new Service at the client would invoke the constructor to get this job done;